# Why is my JFrame not showing even though the JFrame code is executed?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I was making a JFrame for my application that would act as a login panel. After running the class, I noticed a couple of problems. One, eclipse (the IDE I am using) shows that the line has been executed. Setting the JFrame to be visible should make it visible to the user, however, I don't see it on my screen. Additionally, eclipse shows me that the process is still running, and did not exit with an exit code.

My LoginPanel.java:

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Test {

    private JFrame frmLogin;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test window = new Test();
        window.frmLogin.setVisible(true);
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public Test() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {

        System.out.println("Opening Login Panel");

        frmLogin = new JFrame();
        frmLogin.setTitle("Test");
        frmLogin.setBounds(100, 100, 585, 380);
        frmLogin.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frmLogin.setVisible(true);

        System.out.println("Window Loaded In");

    }

}
```

After some observations, I have noticed a couple of things. An important thing to notice is that when the EventQueue was commented out, the Logger statement with "Window Loaded In" was outputted in the log, meaning the previous lines of code were already executed. However, still, no window was shown.

**What I Tried:**

I tried adding the statement: `assert frmLogin.isVisible();`, however, the statement said that the JFrame is visible, which doesn't make sense because it isn't showing up on the screen. It seems that all of the code is executing, but the JFrame is still not showing up even I set it to be visible using `frmLogin.setVisible(true);` two times in the initialize() method and the start() method.

Comment: Is it displaying but really tiny? You can set the size before using setvisible to make sure it isn't too small.

Comment: Are you running a debugger? Sometimes if you're at a breakpoint, debuggers will prevent the gui from showing.

Comment: @matt Not working, and also I set bounds to be 585 by 380, please read the code.

Comment: Set bounds is not set size. "Not working" is meaningless. Is the process ending? Or is the process hanging, but you don't see anything. You can take a little bit of your time and reduce all of the cruft and just leave the meaningful parts. We don't need to see the comments.

Comment: @matt Sorry about that. I edited the question and deleted unnecessary code. The process didn't end, and it executed to the last line of code, but the JFrame didn't show up.

Comment: What about the last line of your main, you're completely swallowing that exception. Have you considered just removing it?

Comment: @JavaProgramming19817 It is strange : I removed all the pulsebeat02 stuff and I get an empty window. Is the message "Window Loaded In" present in your log? By the way,  try to remove your call to ´setLookAndField`

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). BTW - the PLAF should be set **before** components are created. But PLAF is likely irrelevant to the problem at hand, so take it out for now and fix that later.

Comment: @C.Champagne After editing all the code and deleting unnecessary lines of code and making the remaining code still reproduce the error, I was left with the code above that would still reproduce the problem with the window not showing up. I made the code available to execute for programmers without my other classes.

Comment: @matt I already tried removing the last line of code. Still, the JFrame isn't showing up, and no Exception, Issue, or Error was thrown.

Comment: The posted code does work (show an empty JFrame). Please tidy up your code by removing all commented out code, to make it more readable.

Comment: @c0der For me, it just shows up nothing. For example, look at the embed link here that I sent you. Eclipse showed the println() statements, however, no window was shown. [link] https://imgur.com/gallery/TFWFVc5  Is there something wrong with my JVM? I am on Mac right now, could that have anything to do with this problem? Also btw, I wished I could "undo" all the downvotes I got. Sadly, I edited the post, however, it is still going to stay at -4.

Comment: 1. See https://imgur.com/a/julhzuq   2. `window.frmLogin.setVisible(true);`  is not needed. 3. To avoid the -4 delete the question. If needed post a new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good news, I have finally found the issue. Turns out that the SWT library I was using interfered with the JFrame somehow. Removing it solved the problem and made the JFrame showup. It seems that SWT still has a lot of problems even after the AWT rewrite of many classes in JDK 1.7.